# MATLAB: Not enough input arguments

Tags: matlab

```
function newv = fun(colv)

    sm = size(colv);
    if(sm(2) ~= 1)
        error('This function works only for column vectors');
    end
    newv = [colv;colv];

end
```

Hi guys
I'm a noob in matlab world.
I'm trying to try out an example about vector practice.
The code above gives a following error:

> >
>   Error using Lab1Problem9 (line 3)
>   Not enough input arguments.

Is there any syntactical error I'm overlooking?

I'd appreciate your input ,

Thanks

Comment: This error will occur if you press run in the function window. Try calling it from the command window, with an argument.

Comment: Hi, I tried calling it from the command window but it says my function "fun" is not defined. I guess due to the error, the code wasn't read through?

Comment: to execute `fun()` from command line, you must be in the folder where fun.m is located, or add this location to the matlab path. And what is Lab1Problem9?

Comment: @Marcin: I expect that is his filename, which doesn't match the function name.  Of course, the function name gets ignored, only the filename matters.